# Dynamic SQL statement based on foreach

Tags: php, mysql

How would I get this to work, because I am just getting errors right now.

`$_GET['providers'] is an array of DB column names, which I am checking if = 1 in the below query.`

```
foreach ($_GET['providers'] as $providers) {
  $statement = "AND ".$providers."= '1' ";
}
$sql = "select * from users where user_id ='1' ".$statement." ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(isset($row['user_id'])){
 echo "It worked";
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to say, it's saying $statement is undefined. The one in the SQL query.

Comment: Oh so many issues with this. First, `$statement` needs to be defined before your foreach. That way if `providers` is empty, the statement already exists. Second, you're overwriting the variable in each loop. You need to concatenate, or build up an array that you could implode later. Third, as seen with the highlighting, your statement attempt is built wrong.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but if this isn't a simplified example, you're *extremely* vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) here.

Comment: @ray it is a simplified example.

Comment: @aynber could you give me an example?

Comment: @aynber also, i just forgot to define statement outside first, sorry.

Comment: If you do a `var_dump($statement)` after the loop, it should make the issues clearer.

Comment: @TaLeNT You seem have asked almost the same question 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a whitelist to check if the `$providers` are known column names. You then should concatenate the `$statement`, otherwise you overwrite that variable on every iteration.

```
$statement = '';
$columns = array('known', 'columns', 'go', 'here');
foreach ($_GET['providers'] as $providers) {
    if(in_array($providers, $columns)) {
           $statement .= " AND $providers = 1 ";
    }
}
$sql = "select user_id from users where user_id =1 $statement limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(isset($row['user_id'])){
    echo "It worked";
}
```

You also shouldn't use `*` unless you really want every column. If you just want to see if a row is returned you also can use `limit 1` because you don't care about other rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting $statement every time the loop is running.

```
$statement = "";
foreach ($_GET['providers'] as $providers) {
    $statement .= "AND ".$providers."= '1' "; // note the ".=" to append
}
$sql = "select * from users where user_id ='1' ".$statement." ";
// to debug: echo "Query :: $sql";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(isset($row['user_id'])){
    echo "It worked";
}
```